# Azure Function PowerShell output HTML file

Tags: html, powershell, azure, azure-functions

I'm writing a Power Shell based Azure Function App and have a requirement to output a HTML file to a storage blob.

I'm using the External File Output through the Function Apps Integrate Menu.

I run the following code to output the HTML to a file.

```
Out-file -FilePath $outputFile -InputObject $html -Encoding ascii
```

Unfortunately, when I link directly to the file the browser downloads the HTML file rather than displaying it. I believe this is some type of Content type issue. When I open the downloaded file the browser then displays it properly.

I've provided a picture of the output file (result.html) in azure storage explorer below
[Image of file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYlEi.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty old but wth. The reason why it's downloading it is because you need to tell the browser to display the html rather than download it using content-type header.

```
Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
     StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
     ContentType = "text/html"
     Body       = $html
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, current Blob binding can't modify content-type using PowerShell.

In case of C#, ICloudBlob type can modify content-type, but that's is not simply.

If you are interest this issue, see also as follows:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/364